# Explain why two graphs are not isomorphic

Tags: graph-theory

[image]

How do i show that these two are not isomorphic? instinctively you can kind of see that they're not, but that's not good enough of an explanation, I don't think.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The graph on the left is bipartite. The graph on the right is not, since it contains a 5-cycle.

Answer (score 5):

For $H$, there is a cycle of length $5$. But for $G$, there is no cycle of length $5$. Therefore, $G$ cannot be isomorphic to $H$.